# Images from css not loading

Tags: webpack

I'm making a simple Website using Webpack.

I have my images in `project/dist/img/`

I have my scss file in `project/src/scss/style.scss`

Inside my scss file I have background images for several elements.  The only way webpack compiles my .scss file is if I define the image URL with a preceding "/".

So `background-image: url('/img/monkey.png')` compiles and everything works fine when I'm using the webpack-dev-server.  But when I build the site and try to view it on a real Web server the images don't show up because of the preceding slash.  In order for the image to show up on the real server, I would need it to be `background-image: url('img/monkey.png')`

But if I try that, webpack will not compile my .scss file and just throws errors telling me that it cannot find the image.

I'm still learning Webpack and I'm not sure how to fix the problem without manually editing the compiled .css file.

Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

Comment: What happens if you use `./` instead of `/` as the preceding slash?

Comment: ERROR in ./src/scss/style.scss
Module build failed: ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './img/hero.jpg' in 'F:\dev\web\project\src\scss'